# React + Redux - component doesn't re-render in a diferente route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following the [Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-3-data-flow) to understand how it works and to use it.

My code is on codesandbox. [Link here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-tutorial-tq0cj?file=/src/App.js)

In the App.js, there is 2 routes. The first route ("/") render 2 components in the same page, first one (AddPostForm) is a form do create a post, and the second (PostsList) is a list of posts. The second route ("/index") render just the PostsList.

So, when I open the 2 pages in my browser, and in the "/" I create a new post, this post show on the list of this page, but, when I check the "/index", the new post doesn't show up.

I want to know this is supposed to happen, and how can I make the PostList in the route "/index" to update too.

Thanks!

Comment: if you add `<Link to="/index">Posts</Link>` to the `NavBar`, you can go to `/index` by clicking on it and see the new post, Redux stores the new post in the memory, it's not consistent, if you refresh the page ( or manually navigating to `/index` ) you'll loose the changes,

Comment: But when I refresh a page, the Redux store refresh too? Because I understand that redux save it value "outside" the React, while serve is running.

Comment: yes, Redux will refresh too, it is outside React , check out https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist if you want to persist Redux state in localStorage so you won't loose it on page refresh

Comment: Okay, Thank you!